# Why do inline-block elements not fit properly within container?

Tags: html, css

I have a container element which has a width of 560px and a height of 80px. Inside the container, I have 7 inline-block elements which are 80 x 80. (80 width by 80 height) But for some reason, the 7th inline-block element is getting cut off. (80 * 7 = 560)

```css
#playerChoice {
      width: 560px;
      height: 80px;
    }

    #playerChoice > .choice {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="playerChoice">
      <div class="choice" id="choice1"></div>
      <div class="choice" id="choice2"></div>
      <div class="choice" id="choice3"></div>
      <div class="choice" id="choice4"></div>
      <div class="choice" id="choice5"></div>
      <div class="choice" id="choice6"></div>
      <div class="choice" id="choice7"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I usually comment out the extra white space, even though it's ugly, because it doesn't require you changing any of your existing code that you've already written.

Comment: Inline-block will include the whitespace between your divs. You have two options... remove all of the whitespace from your HTML and have ugly HTML, or you can make the `choice` be display block instead of display inline-block and float them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements include the extra whitespace that exists in the markup, as well as descender height for letters like *g*, *j*, *p*, *q*, *y*. This extra white space makes the elements larger than you expect them to be.

Though there [are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) to continue using `inline-block` I would recommend using `flexbox` or float them if you cannot use flexbox.

**Flexbox Solution**

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#playerChoice {
  display: flex;
  width: 560px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px dashed indianred;
}

.choice {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="playerChoice">
  <div class="choice" id="choice1">1</div>
  <div class="choice" id="choice2">2</div>
  <div class="choice" id="choice3">3</div>
  <div class="choice" id="choice4">4</div>
  <div class="choice" id="choice5">5</div>
  <div class="choice" id="choice6">6</div>
  <div class="choice" id="choice7">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just looked into this a bit. In my case, I don't have any text on my page, so I was able to set the font-size: 0, as a workaround.